# robocopy to update contents of folder from local to production

Tags: powershell, copy, robocopy

I want to copy some folders from my local to production. The thing is I want to update the production only when the folder structure exists. I cannot use copy paste as well since the name of the files are different, when I do copy paste I end up with 4 files: file 1, file2, file a, file b.

```
Local:
    Directory1: file1, file2
    Directory2: abc.txt, hqyh.txt
Production:
    Directory1: xyz.txt, jht.txt
    Directory2: abc.txt, cde.txt
    Directory3: p.txt, q.txt
    Directory4: t.txt, u.txt
```

My result:

```
Production:
    Directory1: file1, file2
    Directory2: abc.txt, hqyh.txt
```

Desired result:

```
Production:
    Directory1: file1, file2
    Directory2: abc.txt, hqyh.txt
    Directory3: p.txt, q.txt
    Directory4: t.txt, u.txt
```

Code:

```
robocopy.exe C:\Local E:\Production /MIR
```

Comment: You should be able to just use `copy-item` and force it to overwrite the files.

Comment: why is this tagged with Powershell?

Comment: solution using the powershell is also welcome

Comment: Explain "only when the folder structure exists"

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy` can't do what you're asking (skip folders that don't exist in the source) when you run it on the parent folder(s). Run it on the child folders instead.

```
$src = 'C:\Local'
$dst = 'E:\Production'
Get-ChildItem $src | ForEach-Object {
    robocopy $_.FullName (Join-Path $dst $_.Name) /mir
}
```